# LITMUS^RT: How to handle linux kernel deadlock

Tags: linux-kernel, locking, multiprocessing, deadlock, multicore

I'm working on the linux kernel 3.10 patched with LITMUS^RT, a real-time extension with a focus on multiprocessor real-time scheduling and synchronization.

My aim is to write a scheduler that allows a task to migrate from a cpu to another when preempted and only when particular conditions are met. My current implementation is affected by deadlock beetwen cpus as shown by the following error:

```
Setting up rt task parameters for process 1622.
[ INFO: inconsistent lock state ]
3.10.5-litmus2013.1 #105 Not tainted
---------------------------------
inconsistent {IN-HARDIRQ-W} -> {HARDIRQ-ON-W} usage.
rtspin/1620 [HC0[0]:SC0[0]:HE1:SE1] takes:
 (&rq->lock){?.-.-.}, at: [<ffffffff8155f0d5>] __schedule+0x175/0xa70
{IN-HARDIRQ-W} state was registered at:
  [<ffffffff8107832a>] __lock_acquire+0x86a/0x1e90
  [<ffffffff81079f65>] lock_acquire+0x95/0x140
  [<ffffffff81560fc6>] _raw_spin_lock+0x36/0x50
  [<ffffffff8105e231>] scheduler_tick+0x61/0x210
  [<ffffffff8103f112>] update_process_times+0x62/0x80
  [<ffffffff81071677>] tick_periodic+0x27/0x70
  [<ffffffff8107174b>] tick_handle_periodic+0x1b/0x70
  [<ffffffff810042d0>] timer_interrupt+0x10/0x20
  [<ffffffff810849fd>] handle_irq_event_percpu+0x6d/0x260
  [<ffffffff81084c33>] handle_irq_event+0x43/0x70
  [<ffffffff8108778c>] handle_level_irq+0x6c/0xc0
  [<ffffffff81003a89>] handle_irq+0x19/0x30
  [<ffffffff81003925>] do_IRQ+0x55/0xd0
  [<ffffffff81561cef>] ret_from_intr+0x0/0x13
  [<ffffffff8108615a>] __setup_irq+0x20a/0x4e0
  [<ffffffff81086473>] setup_irq+0x43/0x90
  [<ffffffff8184fb5f>] setup_default_timer_irq+0x12/0x14
  [<ffffffff8184fb78>] hpet_time_init+0x17/0x19
  [<ffffffff8184fb46>] x86_late_time_init+0xa/0x11
  [<ffffffff8184ecd1>] start_kernel+0x270/0x2e0
  [<ffffffff8184e5a3>] x86_64_start_reservations+0x2a/0x2c
  [<ffffffff8184e66c>] x86_64_start_kernel+0xc7/0xca
irq event stamp: 8886
hardirqs last  enabled at (8885): [<ffffffff8108dd6b>] rcu_note_context_switch+0x8b/0x2d0
hardirqs last disabled at (8886): [<ffffffff81561052>] _raw_spin_lock_irq+0x12/0x50
softirqs last  enabled at (8880): [<ffffffff81037125>] __do_softirq+0x195/0x2b0
softirqs last disabled at (8857): [<ffffffff8103738d>] irq_exit+0x7d/0x90

other info that might help us debug this:
 Possible unsafe locking scenario:

       CPU0
       ----
  lock(&rq->lock);
  <Interrupt>
    lock(&rq->lock);

 *** DEADLOCK ***

1 lock held by rtspin/1620:
 #0:  (&rq->lock){?.-.-.}, at: [<ffffffff8155f0d5>] __schedule+0x175/0xa70

stack backtrace:
CPU: 1 PID: 1620 Comm: rtspin Not tainted 3.10.5-litmus2013.1 #105
Hardware name: Bochs Bochs, BIOS Bochs 01/01/2011
 ffffffff81bc4cc0 ffff88001cdf3aa8 ffffffff8155ae1e ffff88001cdf3af8
 ffffffff81557f39 0000000000000000 ffff880000000001 ffff880000000001
 0000000000000000 ffff88001c5ec280 ffffffff810750d0 0000000000000002
Call Trace:
 [<ffffffff8155ae1e>] dump_stack+0x19/0x1b
 [<ffffffff81557f39>] print_usage_bug+0x1f7/0x208
 [<ffffffff810750d0>] ? print_shortest_lock_dependencies+0x1c0/0x1c0
 [<ffffffff81075ead>] mark_lock+0x2ad/0x320
 [<ffffffff81075fd0>] mark_held_locks+0xb0/0x120
 [<ffffffff8129bf71>] ? pfp_schedule+0x691/0xba0
 [<ffffffff810760f2>] trace_hardirqs_on_caller+0xb2/0x210
 [<ffffffff8107625d>] trace_hardirqs_on+0xd/0x10
 [<ffffffff8129bf71>] pfp_schedule+0x691/0xba0
 [<ffffffff81069e70>] pick_next_task_litmus+0x40/0x500
 [<ffffffff8155f17a>] __schedule+0x21a/0xa70
 [<ffffffff8155f9f4>] schedule+0x24/0x70
 [<ffffffff8155d1bc>] schedule_timeout+0x14c/0x200
 [<ffffffff8105e3ed>] ? get_parent_ip+0xd/0x50
 [<ffffffff8105e589>] ? sub_preempt_count+0x69/0xf0
 [<ffffffff8155ffab>] wait_for_completion_interruptible+0xcb/0x140
 [<ffffffff81060e60>] ? try_to_wake_up+0x470/0x470
 [<ffffffff8129266f>] do_wait_for_ts_release+0xef/0x190
 [<ffffffff81292782>] sys_wait_for_ts_release+0x22/0x30
 [<ffffffff81562552>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
```

At this point I suppose I see two possible approaches to follow to solve this problem:

1. Release the lock to the current cpu before migrating to the target cpu using the kernel's functions. LITMUS^RT provides a callback in which I can decide which task will execute:

   static struct task_struct* pfp_schedule(struct task_struct * prev) {
   [...]
   if(is_preempted(prev) {
    // release lock on current cpu
    migrate_to_another_cpu();
   }
   [...]
   }

What I think I must do is to release the current lock before the call to migrate_to_another_cpu function, but I still haven't found any way of doing that.

1. The scheduler that I want to implement allows only one task migration at a time, therefore it's theoretically impossible to have a deadlock. For some reasons though the execution of my task set fails and I get the error listed above which I think is identified during some kind of preliminary analisys performed by the linux kernel. This, however is a potential deadlock, it's kind of a warning, and I would like to let my task set to continue its normal execution ignoring it.

Long story short, does anyone know if one of these solutions is possible and, if yes, how to implement it?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: tips or better ideas are very welcome! ;-)

Comment: This is not a deadlock between CPUs.

Comment: Can you explain to me a little more? Thanks!

Comment: The lock is taken by an interrupt handler on the *same* CPU.

Comment: Any tips to solve my problem? I'm sorry but I'm a novice in this field.

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/spinlocks.txt).

Comment: [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/locking)